# Run Xserver as root

Tags: shell-script, root, startx

I am working with an ARMStone a9 board which has iMX6 linux kernel. I am doing an embedded application in which I have to show a video from Ipcamera. The thing is that I attached the screen to my board, I switch my board on, I login as root, I start the Xserver("startx &"), and then I run my application and everything is works properly.

My problem is because I want that when I switch my board on the Xserver run automatically. I do an script in which I execute the command "startx &", but it does start.

I have been investigated and I find out that the Xserver should be run as root, then I think that when the script starts and run the Xserver run it without root privileges then run wrong.

But I do not know how can I run the Xserver as root and if is possible in automatically way.

Thanks guys

Comment: What distribution are you using? In “I execute the command "startx &", but it does start”, did you forget a “not” before “start” — otherwise what's the problem? How are you running that script?

Comment: Yeah sorry I explained wrong, it does start but start not properly, actually if I try to run my application after this my application does not works. I create the script and I rename this as S60Script.sh and I put it in the init.d

Comment: What distribution are you using? How do you start the application? Are there any error messages?

Comment: here are the spec of my board http://www.fs-net.de/en/products/armstone/armstonea9/.Ok If I do not have the script and I switch my board on, and then login as root I type "startx &" and then I run my application "./application" and everything is ok. But if I use the script, and then I login as root and try to run my application it does not work. No there is not message error, just I can see on the screen squares when I run my applciation, no video no nothing